# How to remove unselected treeview nodes

Tags: c#, treeview

How can i remove unselected treeview nodes. Even if i loop twice is still need to click the button three times before all unselected treenodes are removed.
This is what is have:

```
    private void buttonShowSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
                for (int i = 0; i < treeViewFilter.Nodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    DeleteUnselectedNodes();               
                }
            }


 private void DeleteUnselectedNodes()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < treeViewFilter.Nodes.Count; i++)
     {
         TreeNode aNode = treeViewFilter.Nodes[i];
         treeViewFilter.SelectedNode = aNode.FirstNode;

         if (!aNode.Checked)
         {
             treeViewFilter.Nodes.Remove(aNode);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops don't inspect any of the child nodes.  A recursive function or a stack can work:

```
var nodes = new Stack<TreeNode>(treeViewFilter.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
while (nodes.Count > 0) {
  var n = nodes.Pop();
  if (!n.Checked) {
    if (n.Parent != null) {
      n.Parent.Nodes.Remove(n);
    } else {
      treeViewFilter.Nodes.Remove(n);
    }
  } else {
    foreach (TreeNode tn in n.Nodes) {
      nodes.Push(tn);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should walk the tree recursively;

```
private void buttonShowSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>(treeViewFilter.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
    foreach (var treeNode in nodes)
    {
        DeleteUnselectedNodes(treeNode);
    }
}

private void DeleteUnselectedNodes(TreeNode node)
{
    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>(node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>());
    foreach (var treeNode in nodes)
    {
        DeleteUnselectedNodes(treeNode);
    }

    if (!node.Checked)
    {
        var parent = node.Parent;
        if (parent != null) //If it isn't root
        {
            parent.Nodes.Remove(node);
        }
        else
        {
            treeViewFilter.Nodes.Remove(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. No treeview nodes is removed now.

Comment: I have just tested it. There would be no problem.

Comment: A TreeView control with three nodes all unchecked, no child nodes, your code removes node 1 and 3, node 2 is still there.

Comment: @LarsTech, thats true, thanks. I updated the answer.

Comment: Well... try one parent node checked, two child nodes unchecked.  It only removes one of the child nodes.